# CORS-Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I just started to Learn Angular and I am in process of consuming REST API from Oracle Fusion HCM.
When running the project in Netbeans Tomcat and Also as war file deployed to Oracle Java cloud service I am getting the following **debugging console of firefox or chrome Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing**

I understood what is this in a simple google search that its a server restrictions and it needs to be configured in the server of rest api where it is exposed

But believe me i ran the same Rest api in Pure javascript function and it is retrieving the values with no issues.
So can some one help me out whats wrong in angular code below

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Employee Details Using AngularJS</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 

<p>Employee Details from JCS-SX</p>

<p>{{myWelcome}}<p>

</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http({
method : "GET",
url : "https://****-test.hcm.em2.oraclecloud.com/hcmCoreApi/resources                                       /11.1.11/emps/",
headers: 
        {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' +'ZmDSAScsSDdsSASC=',
            'Content-Type': 'application/jsonp; charset=utf-8'
        }
}).then(function mySuccess(response) {
  $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
}, function myError(response) {
  $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
});



});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: configure backend so that it can accept your request

Answer (score 2):

You need add middleware accept cross domain on you API server

Answer (score -1):

You need to explicitly allow your front-end domain to access your backend. If you are developing you can set the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header the same as your request "Origin" header:

```
resp.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", self.set_allowed_origin_header(req.get_header('Origin')))
```

(This is python code, but you should be able to implement the same in your backend)

In production you should explicity set the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" the same as you front-end domain.